# How to include legacy PHP code hierarchy in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, include, require, relative-path

I am porting a legacy PHP application to Laravel and need to include functions defined in various PHP files into Laravel controllers.  Copying these files into the Laravel project would not be convenient because they will still be used in non-Laravel parts of the site and I want to make sure the code is still shared.  How can I use `require()` somewhere in Laravel with relative paths to all the legacy PHP files?

For instance at the top of the page I am converting to Laravel:

```
<?php

require("../include.php");
require_once("../../trades/trades_include.php");
require_once("account_access_page.php");
require_once("../includes/accounts.php");
```

As you can see, ../include.php includes other files with relative paths:

```
<?php

require_once("general.php");

require_once("../../config.php");
require_once("../../includes/utility.php");
require_once("../../includes/session_helper.php");

require_once("../../includes/date.php");
require_once("../../includes/form.php");
require_once("../../includes/mysql.php");
require_once("../../includes/page.php");
require_once("../../includes/table.php");
```

**EDIT: Including files in `composer.json` does not solve my problem because the nested `require_once()`s fail.  Does anyone know a workaround?**

Answer (score 6):

Probably the best way to load your files is using composer. Go to your `composer.json` in the root of your Laravel application and add this to the `"autoload"` section:

```
"files": [
    "../include.php",
    "../../trades/trades_include.php"
    // and so on...
],
```

The paths are relative to the directory `composer.json` is in.

After adding the files, run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @Andy You will probably need to run `composer dump-autoload` in the project root after you do the above.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Doesn't this mean they'll be loaded for every single route in the application?  It would be nice to only load them for routes that need them.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I just added the files to `composer.json`, but the nested `require()`s didn't work.  When I go to the page I get `Warning: require_once(../../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /vagrant/pub/ca/include.php on line 5
`

Comment: @Andy Yes this would be included for every route. The nested requires probably don't work because the relative paths are now wrong... I'll get back to you if I find something that works.

Comment: Argh, this just isn't working well, even when I copied over the Legacy code and added the files to composer.json, global variables from the included files don't seem to be visible to other files.  I'm still new to PHP too, I'm not very sure how I should attack this problem.

Comment: @Andy I'm sorry to hear that. Are you using Laravel 4 or 5?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Laravel 5.  By this point I've given up and just ported parts of the Legacy code I need, including replacing usage of mysqli to DB::select() etc...I thought half the point of using Laravel as opposed to something like AngularJS these days was being able to integrate with legacy PHP code, but apparently not.

Comment: Have you tried including the files in `bootstrap/autoload.php`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter No...so I've learned one thing.  Part of the problem with the relative paths is that Laravel compiles all of your php into somewhere in `resources/storage`, so it's not running at the same path as you wrote it.  I think that's the root of the problem, I could get the top-level includes to work by making the paths relative to `resources/storage`, but I think the nested includes were weird (one to many `.../` or something like that).  I'm not sure if `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` work in Laravel, I'm guessing not, since everything gets compiled into a different location.

Comment: @lukasgeiter In any case, my boss has me working on other things at the moment...I was able to port the legacy code I needed into Laravel to use it.  I was just hoping to have a more maintainable solution where if someone made changes in the legacy code it would reflect in the Laravel app as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can review this link  :

Legacy to Laravel: How to Modernize an Aging PHP Application

https://tighten.com/insights/converting-a-legacy-app-to-laravel/